# does #opshub allow one VSTS (previously Visual Studio Online) to another VSTS project

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

It seems  #opshub allows migration from on-premise TFS to another Visual Studio Team Services account? Is there tool available to migrate source code from one Visual Studio Team Services account to another

Comment: I get error "You can only select local Team Foundation Server's team project" when selecting source end point

Answer (score -1):

While the Free version of OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility ([OVSMU](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2)) only supports on-prem TFS to VSTS migration. The Commercial version of the tool supports all variations of migration (including TFS to TFS, VSTS to VSTS and VSTS to TFS) along with many more features.

Comment: Could you make this more obvious in the description and error messages. I just ran into the same problem and it is a pity to have to google for why this is not working.